# get control to youtube movie player

Tags: ios, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to control all the events of the youtube MPMoviePlayerViewController (start/stop/finish loading...).

I'm looking for an answer for a lot of hours, that makes me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: YouTube videos are **not** played back using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can control Youtube player object. with supported API.

please refer to this Manual first, https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference.

and let me give you a simple chrome extension which I made.

https://github.com/sunglim/Youtube-Auto-Replay

.thanks